# Parsing pandas tables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (probably dumb) issue with pandas' tables. Let's say I have a table with, among the others, a column named 'lett', that includes a single letter for each row, and a column named 'num', with a number. I also have the following 2 lists

```
letter=["A", "B", "C"]

number=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Now, I want to extract all the rows with A in the letter column and 1 or 2 in the number column, B with 3 or 4 and C with 5 or 6.

My idea was to run

```
table['num'].isin(number[letter.index(table['lett'])])
```

But I get the following issue: *ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().* (maybe because *table['lett']* does not refer to the specific row, but to the whole possible values included in the 'lett' column?). 
What am I supposed to do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make your two `list`s to `list` of `tuple` , then make your `columns` number and letter to a `tuple` as well , then we can using `isin`

```
tup=[(x,z)for x , y in zip(letter,number) for z in y ]
yourdf=df[df[['letter','Number']].apply(tuple,axis = 1).isin(tup)]
```

---

Or using `merge`

```
pd.DataFrame(tup,columns=['letter','number']).merge(df,how='left')
```

Comment: does `apply` function here need `axis=1` argument ?